# How do I compare 2 separate csv files using Pandas and store it into a dictionary?

Tags: python, pandas

So I have 2 csv files. The first one is SortedPower.csv which has

```
ID, Stat, Level, Power, Level_Area
12, A,   Silver,  546.0,  3
11, A,   Silver,  546.0,  3
13, A,   Silver,  561.0,  3
14, A,   Silver,  568.0,  3
15, B,   Silver,  569.0,  3
16, C,   Silver,  562.0,  2
```

The second one is Code.csv which has

```
Code, Stat, C_Code, Name,  Level_Area
36749, A,  01001,  Aut,  3
36703, A,  01001,  Aut,  1
36003, B,  01001,  Aut,  3
36008, A,  01001,  Aut,  3
```

Using pandas I want to compare if

```
Code.csv (Stat and Level_Area) == SortedPower.csv (Stat and Level_Area).
```

If it is I want to take the 2nd lowest Power (for this example Stat A, Level_Area 3, is matched so I'm taking 561.0 because it is the 2nd lowest Power not counting duplicates). And store it into a dictionary along with Code.csv 'Code' for Key, and SortedPower.csv 'Power' for value.

```
Dic_Code_Power = {36749:561.0}
```

So to start I have to create variables to read the csv with Pandas.

```
codes = pd.read_csv("Code.csv")
sortedPower = pd.read_csv("SortedPower.csv")
```

but if I use a for loop to try and compare or add this I'm "getting too many values to unpack (expected 2)", what is the correct way to approach this?

Comment: How are you deciding to choose which `Code` value to pick from `Code.csv`, because there are `2` codes(`36749` and `36008`) for `Stat = A` and `Level_Area = 3`?

Comment: So in this case it would keep adding to the dictionary {36749:561.0, 36008:561.0} every time it matches it will always take the 2nd lowest value and append with the code, the code will always be unique